# Using ps for threads

Tags: linux, bash, memory, memory-management, process

I want to check the contribution of process threads to the process' RSS, VSZ and SZ values. How can I do this.
Because if I do this:

```
ps w -eL -o pid,tid,%cpu,cputime,%mem,sz,rss,vsz,command
```

I get the tid, but all other values for **all the threads of a process** are the same. Can I even do this using ps?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Threads don't have individual contribution to resident and virtual size since they share memory by definition. As for the areas that happen to be in use by a single thread and never shared with other threads, the kernel doesn't know about that. This is why ps shows the same values for all threads in a process.